# Install Samba on Windows 7

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-7, samba, domain-controller

I'm trying to install samba on windows 7.  However, I can't seem to find a windows version of the source to install it with.  Does anybody have a link to a windows version or a way to hack the linux version to work on windows?

BACKGROUND:

The reason I am trying to install samba on a windows machine is because I plan to use it as a DNS/DHCP server as well as a domain controller on a windows 7 machine.  I want to do this with open source products if at all possible.  If anybody has another way to do it, it would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Bad idea. Either run samba on *nix, where it's meant to be run or pay up and purchase a Windows Server license.

Answer (score 5):

This will never work since the native Windows bits that Samba emulates are impossible to turn off. If you need to build a domain controller, you'll have to do it with Linux+Samba or Windows Server. These days those are the only choices.

Comment: Samba runs on other *nix systems besides Linux...

Comment: @ChrisS I was in a hurry!